# How can loop through different text fields which have same class name

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

MY HTML

```
<div class='participants'>

        <div class="participant_period" data-view="scorecards&#x2F;participant_edit" data-model_id="348292" data-model_name="scorecard_participants" data-view-data.model="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;model&quot;,&quot;key&quot;:&quot;model:scorecard_participants:348292&quot;,&quot;model&quot;:&quot;scorecard_participants&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;348292&quot;}" data-model-name="scorecard_participants" data-model-id="348292"><div class="content-item content-full content-results content-box-score">

    <span class="profile-image"><img src="//d3f4b3d8pglafo.cloudfront.net/system/teams/images/348292/thumb/profile" /></span>
    <span class="profile-name"><a href="/teams/web-driver-baseball-team1-348292">Web-driver Baseball Team1</a></span>
    <div class='row'>




      <div class='col col-control'>
        <div class='final-header'>Score</div>
        <div class='period-score'>
          <input name=final_score type="text" size="5" placeholder="-" value="" />

        </div>
      </div>



  </div>
</div>
</div>

        <div class="participant_period" data-view="scorecards&#x2F;participant_edit" data-model_id="347821" data-model_name="scorecard_participants" data-view-data.model="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;model&quot;,&quot;key&quot;:&quot;model:scorecard_participants:347821&quot;,&quot;model&quot;:&quot;scorecard_participants&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;347821&quot;}" data-model-name="scorecard_participants" data-model-id="347821"><div class="content-item content-full content-results content-box-score">

    <span class="profile-image"><img src="//d3f4b3d8pglafo.cloudfront.net/system/teams/images/347821/thumb/102px-RedSoxPrimary_HangingSocks.svg.png" /></span>
    <span class="profile-name"><a href="/teams/boston-red-sox-347821">Boston Red Sox</a></span>
    <div class='row'>




      <div class='col col-control'>
        <div class='final-header'>Score</div>
        <div class='period-score'>
          <input name=final_score type="text" size="5" placeholder="-" value="" />

        </div>
      </div>



  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

- I want to fill up the tex fields " input name=final_score " with random data with loop 
  can anyone suggest me how can i do it

my Watir code is like below

def edit_score_fields
    field = @browser.text_field(:name => 'final_score')
    data = rand(1...2)

```
s = @browser.text_fields(:class => "period-score").size


0.upto(s) { |i| @browser.text_field(:name => 'final_score', :index => '#{i}'.to_i).set(data) }
```

end

Comment: Please help me guys ,i am new to this Watir stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@browser.inputs(:name => 'final_score').each do |field|
  field.send_keys data
end
```

Comment: How could accept the answer , can you please tell me , i am new to stackoverflow